# Find linear transformation from the strip $0<x<1$ to itself

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, linear-transformations, transformation

Find the general form of the linear transformation from the strip $0<x<1$ to itself.

Attempt:

The linear transformation has the form $f(z)=az+b$.

We need to find where $a$ and $b$ are.

Let $z=x+yi$ and $A=\{z\in\mathbb C:0<x<1\}$. We want $T(A)=A$.

As $T(A)$ is homeomorphism then $$T(\partial A)=\partial T(A)\\ \implies T(ki\ \cup\ 1+ki)=\partial A=ki\ \cup\ 1+ki$$

case 1:$T(ki\ \cup\ 1+ki)=ki$

case 2: $T(ki\ \cup\ 1+ki)=1+ki$

What does this implies ?

Am I on the right track?

Help please

Comment: You're right up until the point where you write two cases.

Comment: What's inside the brackets is not connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(z) = az+b$ be such affine transformation, where $a,b\in \mathbb{C}$. Up to composing with $z\mapsto 1-z$ we may suppose that $f$ leaves invariant both boundary lines $\{Re(z) = 0 \}$ and $\{Re(z) = 1 \}$.

For $f$ to send $\{Re(z) = 0 \}$ to itself, we must have $a$ real and $b$ purely imaginary. To prove this we only need to see what restrictions that $Re(f(0))=0$ and $Re(f(i))=0$ impose.
$$ 0= Re(f(0)) = Re(b) \Rightarrow b \,{\rm purely\, imaginary}. $$
Using this we have
$$ 0 = Re(f(i)) = Re(ia+b) = Re(ia) = -Im(a) \Rightarrow a\in \mathbb{R}.$$

Next, to leave $\{Re(z) = 1 \}$ we must have $a=1$. To see this we just have to compute the real part of $f(1)$ and force it to be $1$.
$$ 1 = Re(f(1)) = Re(a+b) = a .$$
Therefore  $$ f(z) = z + ci, \, {\rm with }\, c\in \mathbb{R},$$
if $f$ preserves both boundary lines.

To complete, let $g$ be another such transformation that exchanges the boundary lines, then $g(1-z) = z+ bi$ which means $$g(z) = -z + 1+ci,\, {\rm with }\, c\in \mathbb{R}. $$

Conversely, for any given $c\in \mathbb{R}$ the transformations built as above preserve the region $A$.

Comment: Why for $f$ to send ${Re(z)=0}$ to itself, we must have $a$ real and $b$ purely imaginary ?

Comment: You just need to compute the real parts of $f(i)$ and $f(0)$ and force them to vanish.

Comment: $Re{f(i)}=b.$ If it need to vanish then $b=0.$ And then ?

Comment: I edited it. Hopefully  it is clearer now.